# Postgres 9.4 - pg_stat_database and others showing no stats

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

A database server running Postgres 9.4 shows no statistics when running `select * from pg_stat_database` - well only the `numbackends` is non-zero. The `stats_reset` is null.

I haven't been able to find much as to what should be checked in this case, to find out why statistics aren't reported.

`track_counts` and `track_activities` are both set to `on`.

Per the manual:

> PostgreSQL's statistics collector is a subsystem that supports
>   collection and reporting of information about server activity.

I get that, but I can't find how to see if it's working properly.

---

Even more, the `pg_stat_user_tables` returns zeros in all columns and null for `last_vacuum` - even if I run a manual vacuum on the table.